# Question related to date format

Tags: iphone

I have 1 string NSString *string = @"2010-04-16 15:42:58";

now i want to convert it to 16 april

So,my string will be converted to NSString *stringOutPut =@"16 April";

Answer (score 2):

Look at the NSDateFormatter